# Flyway DB migration failed

Tags: flyway

I am getting the following error when I build my DB project which uses Flyway DB...

> Failed to execute goal
>   com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-maven-plugin:2.2.1:migrate (default) on
>   project MyApp-DB: com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException:
>   Migration of schema "LOCAL_APP" to version 3.1.0.4 failed! Please
>   restore backups and roll back database and code!

How do I fix the same ?

Answer (score 1):

The failing statement should also be in the logs (-X for debug). This has also been improved as part of 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

It usually fails due to badly written migration statements. When a sql statement returns a non-zero (error) status, Flyway treats migration as failed, and your database is left in unstable state, you are advised to apply further operations in that migration manually and carefully, then update the last row in `schema_version` table and mark the migration as successful.

Note: Flyway uses transactional migration with some databases, it automatically rollbacks when an error occurs so the database won't be left in an unstable state. In your case, Flyway did not apply transactional migration.